# Overriding Node Wrangler Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: python, interface, add-on, linux

I use Linux Mint, and unfortunately, I can't use a lot of the Node Wrangler shortcuts because they conflict with the Operating System shortcuts.  For example, I can't use Lazy Mix because it moves the window instead.  I went inside the Node Wrangler source code and tried to change it to a differnt short cut (which kind of works...) but I still have to release the right mouse button and such.  Can anybody explain how to get around this OR what each of these parameters represent in the Node Wrangler addon?:

```
# Lazy Mix
(NWLazyMix.bl_idname, 'RIGHTMOUSE', 'PRESS', False, False, True, None, "Lazy Mix"),
```

Edit: If I can do what gandalf3 suggested in the comments, that would work too.

Comment: I typically change the move/resize window shortcut to `Meta` + `Mouse button` in my desktop environment. Blender doesn't use the `meta` modifier key anywhere, and once you get used to it it's kind of logical.. Use the windows key for window operations ;) Solves conflicts with blender all over the place (not just the node wrangler addon).

Comment: @gandalf3 Okay, how do you do that?

Comment: Depends on what window manager/desktop environment you use (KDE, Xfce, Openbox, etc.).

Comment: @gandalf3 It looks like openbox, but let me check. I know my desktop environment is  Cinnamon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I ended up doing was going into the Windows settings and changing the "Special key to move and resize windows" to Super (the windows button) instead of Alt.[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think there might be an option for none also, but this might GNOME 3 only.